# In C++, can you dynamically decide which class to use as a template?

Tags: c++

I have:

```
template <class InputClass>
public Child: public Parent<InputClass>{
   //...
}
```

I am evolving it so that:

```
class A{/**/};
class B{/**/};
class C{/**/};

template <class InputClass>
public Child: public Parent</*either A, B, or C depending on some if or switch statements*/>
}
```

I can't find a way to do this elegantly in C++.

Comment: Check out [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional).

Comment: Template instantiation happens at compile time. So only feasible solution is to instantiate all variants and choose one at runtime.

Comment: Is there some relationship between A/B/C or are they completely dissimilar?

Comment: Go into more detail about that "`if` or `switch` statement" part. It very much depends on the kind of condition whether you can do and how complex this gets...  Specifically it would be interesting to know what kind of data the choice depends on.

Comment: C++ does not work this way. The types of all objects are known at compile time, and cannot be arbitrarily selected, at runtime, based on some if condition or a switch statement. This is fundamental to C++. There are no workarounds or exceptions.

Comment: @MartinYork A/B/C can be made to inherit the same class if necessary, but otherwise completely dissimilar

Comment: @user1008636 Don't force the inheritance. If they are dissimilar then `std::conditional` as suggested by Nathan above sounds like the best path forward I was just seeing if there were alternatives.

Comment: Create three separate classes and select which *objects* get created based on some runtime condition.

Comment: @NathanOliver but the 'condition' must be evaluated at compile time for std::conditional ? What if in my code example, the 'condition' evaluation depends on the value of an input parameter to the constructor of Child class ?

Comment: @user1008636 You can't do that.  C++ requires all types to be known at compile time.  What you can do is use something like `std::variant` and have a `std::variant<Child<A>, Child<B>, Child<C>>` and then you can use visitor pattern to "do the right thing".

Comment: You write `Child<A>` or `Child<B>` or `Child<C>` depending on which one you want.

Comment: @NathanOliver elaborate on the visitor pattern ?

Comment: see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks, that seems overly complex for such a simple use case ?

Comment: mixing compile time and run time gets kind of complex.  They don't mesh well.

Comment: @NathanOliver understood. Is there an alternative refactoring of my above code to achieve the same purpose, which is to selectively decide which class to use as input to the template ? Even if it means doing some copy pasting work ?

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing.  I'd need to know more to be able to suggest how to refactor.  Can you detail in the question what you're actually trying to solve doing this?